# Powershell - find file names within a string when their names are unknown - only their extension is known ".jpg"?

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, how can I get a list of file names within a string, if I only know the extension?

Simplified example:

```
C:\> $e = "CN=Ken Myer world.jpg more text."
C:\> $f = $e.IndexOf(".jpg")
C:\> write-host $f
17
```

How do I get the rest of the unknown file name?
(Assuming a 5 character file name) I can not plug in a negative number into $e.Substring(17,-5,9)  <--does not work.

Comment: RegEx will help here, but you need to figure out a recurring pattern to match. For example, the file names can have spaces but are all terminated by ".jpg" obviously. If they all have "=" before them, you can construct a suitable RegEx easily. See the following pages for help: [1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html), [2](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4310.powershell-working-with-regular-expressions-regex.aspx), [3](http://www.gfi.com/blog/windows-powershell-extracting-strings-using-regular-expressions/).

Answer (score 0):

$regex = '\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-+]+.jpg'

select-string -Path $DL_file -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $*.Matches } | % { $*.Value } > $CurrentFileNames

Seems to work for my situation.

Thanks!